# the play button slides down when zooming in

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, zoom-sdk

[normal scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U63Wa.png)

[zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzZNg.png)

the play button slides down when zooming in, but the other elements remain in their places. I've been trying to figure out how to fix it for a long time, I tried to close it all in a sticky container and make the form a child element, but it didn't help solve the problem

the code responsible for the player:

```
.white button{
    position: absolute;

}
    
#play{
    position: absolute;
    width: 7vw;
    height: 3vw;
    margin-top: -78vh;
    margin-left: 30vw;
    font-family: 'Clash Display', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    border-radius: 150px;
    border-style: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    padding-left: 2.6vw;
    }

.playpause {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: auto;
    
  }
  
  .playpause .button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1.1vw;
    height: 1.1vw;
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
    transition: inherit;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 25%, 50% 75%, 50% 75%, 50% 25%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
    margin-top: -39.4vw;
    margin-left: 29.9vw; 
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  
  .playpause.playing .button {
      position: absolute;
     clip-path: polygon(0 0, 40% 0, 40% 100%, 60% 100%, 60% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
     color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }

<div class="playpause">
        <div class="button"></div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
        <form
         class="white button"><input type="button" value="Play" id="play">
        </form>

<script>
      const playpause = document.querySelector('.playpause');
        playpause.addEventListener('click', () => {
          playpause.classList.toggle('playing');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Good that you added image links in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` & `left` property to position and avoid using margins for positioning in css.
Second, use `position: relative;` on the parent of your button to avoid mess.

Comment: thx. it was a good feedback

Comment: But, did it solve your issue? @ШПИПСИКCHANNEL

Comment: yes it helped. this is a good solution